# Make update Apex trigger run on old records

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I've written an apex trigger than runs when an `Event` is updated, and makes a callout to an external application (a slack app) to update details about that event in slack. The trigger just makes a callout with the `Id`.

Because of recent changes, now the external representation (in slack) of some old events is now inaccurate. I need the update trigger to run on those old events.

I want to run a query to select a group of records that would look like

```
Select Id from Event where RecordTypeId = '...' AND ...
```

with a few other filter options. I expect the set of records to be a few hundred.

I want to then force my update trigger to run on those applications. If this is not possible, can I write an apex script that will select a set of records and make a callout for each one? Ideally I'd like to set a 1000ms wait timer between each one to avoid overloading my external application if possible.

What is the best course of action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with existing data, use a tool like workbench or dataloader to export the data you want the trigger to be executed on, then upload the same data to your org using an **upsert** operation. This will ensure any before/after update logic is run.

If the number of records is only a few hundred and it's a one-off activity, you could run a script that follows the same approach.

```
Integer counter = 0; // Increment this every run
Integer batchSize = 500;
Integer offset = counter * batchSize;

Event[] myEvents = [select Id from Event where ... limit :batchSize offset :offset];

upsert myEvents;
```

Adjust `batchSize` to your own requirements (i.e. reduce it if you don't want to overload your third party service). You'll have to re-run it for as many increments as you need to cover the amount of record you want to update.

Otherwise you may want to consider writing a batch class to process thousands of records.

Comment: I see. And I could run this script from the production (ie non sandbox) dev console execute anonymous window?

Comment: Yes, try it from the developer console if you are able to access it in your prod environment.